# Reflect follow camera blender 3.4

Tags: shader-nodes

I try to make the glass sphere reflect in the same direction as I move the camera
[image]
I tried *Noise Texture* but it didn't work.
[image][image]
I hope to get better method. I thank you very much.

Comment: do you mean that you want to keep the reflections at the same position?

Comment: I mean when I rotate view the reflections will be in the same position